# simpleGal thumbnails don't control slider when inside seperate div

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this thumbnail slider from simpleGal: https://github.com/steverydz/simpleGal

However, when I put the thumbnails inside their own div they stop controlling the slider.

I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone help?

Here's an example of how it works without a div surrounding the thumbnails and doesn't with one: http://searchtransparency.net/air/the-icon-test.html

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to remove the dots.  You should be able to add the following to the css on your ul.

```
list-style: none;
```